# Oracle view that passes values from a table to a function?

Tags: oracle, function

I am trying to create an Oracle view that will show two columns:

Employee_ID, Department_ID

To get department_id, I need to pass an employee_id into a function which I am doing today with:

```
select * from TABLE(user.fn_department('dept',employee_id)
```

This will give me only a list of department_ids for the employee_id I pass into it.

I can get a list of unique employees from the employee table.

How do I combine these two outputs?

Thank you!

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: A table function that returns single rows isn't very efficient imho. I suggest you bypass/avoid the function. Just use the logic contained in the function as a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW USER_DEPT_VIEW AS
  SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID,
         USER.FN_DEPARTMENT('dept', e.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS DEPARTMENT_ID
    FROM EMPLOYEE e;
```

which you could then use as e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_dEPT_VIEW
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 1234
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you Bob!! This is incredible close. The only issue I am having now is that the data is coming back as a single cell "<Collection>" in Oracle instead of values. Could this be because some employees have multiple departments? If so, anyway to display the actual employee_ids/department_ids even if its multiple rows?

Comment: What's the return type of `USER.FN_DEPARTMENT`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT b.employee_id, a.department_id
  FROM employees b, table(user.fn_department('dept',b.employee_id)) a
 ORDER by b.employee_id
```